# Finding the script element in a String with strpos | PHP

Tags: php

How can I find a  element in a string with the php function `strpos`. I get a parse error whenever I execute the function with the $error string.

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]   parse error

```
 $error =  'You have an error in your SQL syntax;            
           check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version    
           for the right syntax to use near 
           '"=<script>alert('o7v87r99ib')</script>"' at line 1';

           $str = '=<script>alert('o7v87r99ib')</script>';

                if(strpos($error, $str)){
                    echo 'Found: ' . $str;
                }
```

Comment: The syntax highlighting shows you your error

Comment: escape the quotes: `$str = '=<script>alert(\'o7v87r99ib\')</script>';`

Comment: Exactly. Rewrite $str = '=<script>alert('o7v87r99ib')</script>'; to $str = "=<script>alert('o7v87r99ib')</script>";

Comment: @JohnConde I know what causes the error but I don't know the solution.

Comment: same goes for `$error` string. sort your quotes there, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple errors, your `$error` string is not a valid string. You are also missing the `$` from `str` in your echo.

```
<?php
 $error =  'You have an error in your SQL syntax;            
           check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version    
           for the right syntax to use near 
           \'"=<script>alert(\'o7v87r99ib\')</script>"\' at line 1';

$str = "=<script>alert('o7v87r99ib')</script>";

if(strpos($error, $str)){
    echo 'Found: ' .$str;
}
```